# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Data.Entity.DbSet

Tags: linq

I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'. 
> An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have the following code:

```
var reports = dbContext.Product;

if (searchField == "StoreNum")
{
    int storeNum;
    int? stnum = int.TryParse(searchString, out storeNum) ? storeNum : (int?)null;

    reports = dbContext.Product
        .Where(w => w.StoreNum == stnum); // error occurs here when I try to build
}
```

I cannot understand why I am getting this message.

Comment: Isn't reports supposed to be a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var reports = dbContext.Product.ToList();

        if (searchField == "StoreNum")
        {
            int storeNum;
            int? stnum = int.TryParse(searchString, out storeNum) ? storeNum : (int?)null;

           reports = reports
          .Where(w => w.StoreNum == stnum).AsQueryable(); // error occurs here when I try to build

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
List<ProdVal> reports;

if (searchField == "StoreNum")
    {
        int storeNum;
        int? stnum = int.TryParse(searchString, out storeNum) ? storeNum : (int?)null;

       reports = (dbContext.Product
                 .Where(w => w.StoreNum == stnum)).ToList(); // error occurs here when I try to build

    }
```

Comment: Return type is  public IEnumerable<ProdVal>