# Filtering data from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have simple method where I retrieve data from database and send it to the View. But in the meantime data need to filtered. I have below code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Manufacturer)
    {
        var dev = db.Devices;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            dev = dev.Where(w => w.Name.Contains(Name));
        }
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Manufacturer))
        {
            dev = dev.Where(w => w.Manufacturer.Contains(Manufacturer));
        }
        return View(dev.ToList());
    }
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I tried adding cast eg:

```
(DbSet<Device>)
```

But didn't helped. Can anyone suggest me how to modify my code?

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788425/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryable-to-system-data-entity-dbs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `db.Devices` will be a `DbSet<Device>` collection, not an `IQueryable<T>`, so on these lines

```
dev = dev.Where(...)
```

the `Where` will return `IQueryable<T>` and given `DbSet<T>` can't be implicitly set as `IQueryable<T>` you get an exception.

What you need to do here is convert your `DbSet<T>` to an `IQueryable<T>` and that can be done pretty easily by calling [AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) i.e.

```
var dev = db.Devices.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 4):

By

```
var dev = db.Devices;
```

you declare `dev` to be of type `DbSet<Device>`. The Where-methods return an IQueryable and therefore, you cannot use the variable `dev`. Change the declaration as follows:

```
var dev = db.Devices.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: You mean `IQueryable<Device>`.